# Python: re.sub pattern and replacement wildcard

Tags: python, design-patterns, replace

I have been going this bit of code for what seems to be a lifetime and cannot seem to get it to work.

```
pattern = "\[([a-zA-Z0-9].*?)#([a-zA-Z0-9].*?)\]"
pattern_obj = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
translation = pattern_obj.sub("<ol>\\1</ol>", translation)
```

What I am trying to do here is change some text, i.e.:

```
[ 
  # This is item number one in an ordered list. #

  # And this is item number two in the same list. #
]
```

Into:

```
<ol> 
#This is item number one in an ordered list. #
#And this is item number two in the same list. #
</ol>
```

Essentially, it is supposed to identify any text between [ and ] with a # somewhere in the text, and change the [ into `<ol>` and ] into `</ol>` whilst keeping all internal text the same. Can anyone please advise?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does almost what you want:

```
>>> re.compile(r"\[([^\]]*)\]").sub("<ol>\\1</ol>", "b[#a]c")
'b<ol>#a</ol>c'
```

The `[^\]]` take every character except ] after the `\[` clsing bracket.

With an the `#` it would look like this:

```
>>> re.compile(r"\[([^\]]*#[^\]]*)\]").sub("<ol>\\1</ol>", "b[#a]c")
'b<ol>#a</ol>c'
>>> re.compile(r"\[([^\]]*#[^\]]*)\]").sub("<ol>\\1</ol>", "b[gggg]c")
'b[gggg]c'
```

The `.` is always a bit of a problem if you want to find something between something.